# Update-database "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, relational-database, entity-framework-migrations

I was recently trying to remove a field from my database, and now every time I try and run `Update-database` I get this error:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

[Full Error description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP8M3.png)
[Sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeKlu.png)

I used

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName ArtistDatabase.Models.ArtistDBContext 

Add-Migration Initial 

Update-database.
```

Artist.Cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ArtistDatabase.Models
{
public class Artist
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Required,StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3), Display(Name = "Artist")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth"),DataType(DataType.Date),DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Required,StringLength(30)]
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Display(Name = "Art Style/Movement")]
    public string ArtStyle { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Info { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Display(Name = "Famous work: "),DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Artwork1 { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Display(Name = " "), DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Artwork2 { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Display(Name = " "), DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Artwork3 { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
}
}
```

Configuration.Cs (seed method)

```
 namespace ArtistDatabase.Migrations
{
using Models;
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ArtistDatabase.Models.ArtistDBContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ArtistDatabase.Models.ArtistDBContext context)
    {
        context.Artists.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Name,
            new Artist
            {
                Name = "Pablo Ruiz y Picasso",
                Picture = "http://a5.files.biography.com/image/upload/c_fit,cs_srgb,dpr_1.0,h_1200,q_80,w_1200/MTE1ODA0OTcxNzU0MDk2MTQx.jpg",
                BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("25-10-1881"),
                Nationality = "Spanish",
                ArtStyle = "Cubism, Surrealism",
                Info = "Picasso was a Spanish painter, sculptor and ceramicist, among other things. He spent most of his adult life in France, " +
                "and is regarding as one of the greatest and most influential artists of the 20th century. He is known as co-founding of the" +
                " 'Cubist' movement; the invention of constructed sculpture, also being the co-inventor of collage, and for the wide variety" +
                " of styles that he helped develop and explore. Picasso, Henri Matisse and Marcel Duchamp are regarded as the three artists" +
                " who most defined the revolutionary developments in the plastic arts in the opening decades of the 20th century, responsible" +
                " for significant developments in painting, sculpture, printmaking and ceramics. Picasso demonstrated extraordinary artistic" +
                " talent in his early years, painting in a naturalistic manner through his childhood and adolescence.During the first decade" +
                " of the 20th century, his style changed as he experimented with different theories, techniques, and ideas.His work is often" +
                " categorized into periods.While the names of many of his later periods are debated, the most commonly accepted periods in his" +
                " work are the Blue Period(1901–1904), the Rose Period(1904–1906), the African - influenced Period(1907–1909)," +
                " Analytic Cubism(1909–1912),and Synthetic Cubism(1912–1919),also referred to as the Crystal period. Exceptionally prolific" +
                " throughout the course of his long life, Picasso achieved universal renown and immense fortune for his revolutionary artistic" +
                " accomplishments, and became one of the best - known figures in 20th - century art.",
                Rating = "",
                Artwork1 = "https://mocochocodotcom.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/how-to-recognize-painters-by-their-work-picasso2.jpg",
                Artwork2 = "http://paintingandframe.com/uploadpic/pablo_picasso/big/les_demoiselles_d_avignon_c_1907.jpg",
                Artwork3 = "http://www.themost10.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Blue-Nude-By-Pablo-Picasso.jpg?09df94"
            },

            new Artist
            {
                Name = "Leonardo da Vinci",
                Picture = "http://www.leonardodavinci.net/images/leonardo-da-vinci.jpg",
                BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("15-04-1452"),
                Nationality = "Italian",
                ArtStyle = "High Renaissance",
                Info = "Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci was an Italian polymath whose areas of interest included invention, painting," +
                " sculpting, architecture, science, music, mathematics, engineering, literature, anatomy, geology, astronomy, botany, writing, history," +
                " and cartography. He has been variously called the father of palaeontology, ichnology, and architecture, and is widely considered one" +
                " of the greatest painters of all time. Sometimes credited with the inventions of the parachute, helicopter and tank, he epitomised" +
                " the Renaissance humanist ideal.Many historians and scholars regard Leonardo as the prime exemplar of the 'Universal Genius' or " +
                "'Renaissance Man', an individual of 'unquenchable curiosity' and 'feverishly inventive imagination'. According to art historian Helen" +
                " Gardner, the scope and depth of his interests were without precedent in recorded history, and 'his mind and personality seem to us" +
                " superhuman, while the man himself mysterious and remote'. Marco Rosci notes that while there is much speculation regarding his life" +
                " and personality, his view of the world was logical rather than mysterious, and that the empirical methods he employed were unorthodox" +
                "for his time. Leonardo was, and is, renowned primarily as a painter. Among his works, the Mona Lisa is the most famous and most" +
                " parodied portrait and The Last Supper the most reproduced religious painting of all time, their fame approached only by Michelangelo's" +
                " The Creation of Adam. Leonardo's drawing of the Vitruvian Man is also regarded as a cultural icon, being reproduced on items as" +
                " varied as the euro coin, textbooks, and T-shirts. Perhaps fifteen of his paintings have survived. Nevertheless, these few works," +
                " together with his notebooks, which contain drawings, scientific diagrams, and his thoughts on the nature of painting, compose a" +
                " contribution to later generations of artists rivalled only by that of his contemporary, Michelangelo.",
                Rating = "",
                Artwork1 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa,_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci,_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/402px-Mona_Lisa,_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci,_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg",
                Artwork2 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Leonardo_da_Vinci_-_Last_Supper_(copy)_-_WGA12732.jpg",
                Artwork3 = "http://blog.world-mysteries.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/vitruvian_man_mixed.jpg"
            },

            new Artist
            {
                Name = "Georgia O'Keeffe",
                Picture = "http://1874.img.pp.sohu.com.cn/images/blog/2008/11/16/20/26/11e4d90ce26g213.jpg",
                BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("15-11-1887"),
                Nationality = "American",
                ArtStyle = "American Modernism",
                Info = "Georgia Totto O'Keeffe was an American artist. She is best known for her paintings of enlarged flowers, New York skyscrapers," +
                " and New Mexico landscapes. O'Keeffe has been recognized as the 'Mother of American modernism'. O'Keeffe studied at the School of the" +
                " Art Institute of Chicago from 1905 to 1906. In 1907, she attended the Art Students League in New York City, where she studied under" +
                " William Merritt Chase. In 1908, she won the League's William Merritt Chase still-life prize for her oil painting Dead Rabbit with" +
                " Copper Pot. Her prize was a scholarship to attend the League's outdoor summer school in Lake George, New York. While in the city" +
                " in 1908, O'Keeffe attended an exhibition of Rodin's watercolors at the gallery 291, owned by her future husband, photographer Alfred" +
                " Stieglitz. O'Keeffe abandoned the idea of pursuing a career as an artist in late 1908, claiming that she could never distinguish" +
                " herself as an artist within the mimetic tradition which had formed the basis of her art training. She took a job in Chicago as" +
                " a commercial artist. She did not paint for four years, and said that the smell of turpentine made her sick. She was inspired to" +
                " paint again in 1912, when she attended a class at the University of Virginia Summer School, where she was introduced to the innovative" +
                " ideas of Arthur Wesley Dow by Alon Bement. Dow encouraged artists to express themselves using line, color, and shading" +
                " harmoniously. From 1912-14, she taught art in the public schools in Amarillo in the Texas Panhandle. She attended Teachers College" +
                " of Columbia University from 1914–15, where she took classes from Dow, who greatly influenced O'Keeffe's thinking about the process of" +
                " making art. She served as a teaching assistant to Bement during the summers from 1913–16 and taught at Columbia College, Columbia," +
                " South Carolina in late 1915, where she completed a series of highly innovative charcoal abstractions. After further course work at" +
                " Columbia in early 1916 and summer teaching for Bement, she took a job as head of the art department at West Texas State Normal College" +
                " from late 1916 to February 1918, the fledgling West Texas A&M University in Canyon just south of Amarillo. While there, she often" +
                " visited the Palo Duro Canyon, making its forms a subject in her work.",
                Rating = "",
                Artwork1 = "http://www.georgiaokeeffe.net/images/paintings/rams-head.jpg",
                Artwork2 = "https://learnodo-newtonic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Red-Canna-1924-Georgia-OKeeffe.jpg",
                Artwork3 = "http://www.themasterpiececards.com/hs-fs/hub/40667/file-25876050-jpg/images/okeeffe_jack_2_from_nga-resized-600.jpg?t=1465250810631"
            },

            new Artist
            {
                Name = "Vincent van Gogh",
                Picture = "http://site.artsheaven.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/vincent.jpg",
                BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("30-03-1853"),
                Nationality = "Dutch",
                ArtStyle = "Post-Impressionism",
                Info = "Vincent Willem van Gogh was a Dutch painter who is among the most famous and influential figures in the history of Western art." +
                " In just over a decade he created about 2100 artworks, including around 860 oil paintings, most of them in the last two years of his" +
                " life. They include landscapes, still lifes, portraits and self-portraits, and are characterised by bold, symbolic colours, and" +
                " dramatic, impulsive and highly expressive brushwork that contributed to the foundations of modern art. He sold only one painting" +
                " during his lifetime and became famous after his suicide at age 37, which followed years of poverty and mental illness. Van Gogh's" +
                " early works, mostly still lifes and depictions of peasant labourers, contain few signs of the vivid colour that distinguished his" +
                " later work. In 1886 he moved to Paris and discovered the French Impressionists. As his work developed he created a new approach to" +
                " still lifes and local landscapes. His paintings grew brighter in colour as he developed a style that became fully realised during his" +
                " stay in Arles in the south of France in 1888. He lived there in the Yellow House and, with the French artist Paul Gauguin, developed a" +
                " concept of colour that symbolised inner emotion. During this period he broadened his subject matter to include olive trees, cypresses," +
                " wheat fields and sunflowers. In Nuenen, Van Gogh focused on painting and drawing. Working outside and very quickly, he completed" +
                " sketches and paintings of weavers and their cottages. In August 1884, Margot Begemann, a neighbour's daughter and ten years" +
                " his senior, began joining him on his painting forays; she fell in love, and he reciprocated, though less enthusiastically. They" +
                " decided to marry, but the idea was opposed by both families, following which Margot took an overdose of strychnine. She was saved" +
                " when Van Gogh rushed her to a nearby hospital. On 26 March 1885, his father died of a heart attack. Van Gogh painted several" +
                "groups of still lifes in 1885. During his two - year stay in Nuenen, he completed numerous drawings and watercolours, and nearly" +
                "200 oil paintings.His palette consisted mainly of sombre earth tones, particularly dark brown, and showed no sign of the vivid colours" +
                "that distinguish his later work.Considered a madman and a failure in his lifetime,Van Gogh exists in the public imagination as the" +
                "quintessential misunderstood genius, the artist 'where discourses on madness and creativity converge'.His reputation began to grow" +
                "in the early 20th century as elements of his painting style came to be incorporated by the Fauves and German Expressionists.He attained" +
                "widespread critical, commercial and popular success over the ensuing decades, and is remembered as an important but tragic painter," +
                "whose troubled personality typifies the romantic ideal of the tortured artist.",
                Rating = "",
                Artwork1 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg",
                Artwork2 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/Vincent_van_Gogh_-_De_slaapkamer_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/1280px-Vincent_van_Gogh_-_De_slaapkamer_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg",
                Artwork3 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/Vincent_Willem_van_Gogh_128.jpg/175px-Vincent_Willem_van_Gogh_128.jpg"
            }

        );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well, what do these **inner exceptions** tell you that the error message is telling you to inspect?

Comment: @marc_s My apologies I didn't know where to look, but on inspection I found this 'The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

Comment: This can happen if you do not assign a value to a DateTime field when the field does not accept NULL values.

Comment: @Tarzan Wouldn't this format be ok?  'BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("25-10-1881"),'

Comment: Unclear: not reproducible, all dates are later than January 1, 1753.

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing an error as the string is not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("25-10-1881")
```

The resolution is to rewrite the line using ParseExtract like this.

```
BirthDate = DateTime.ParseExact("25-10-1881", "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

Also, make sure that the SQL Server field will allow the values you are attempting to save.

Comment: I've just tried this and still nothing, same 'out-of-range' exception.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace so we can see more information about the error?

Comment: Here is an image of the full error https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP8M3.png .

Comment: The inner exception is a SqlException, so it's being generated by the SqlClient provider. In other words, the error is generated by the database. The SQL Server datetime datatype  is capable of storing dates in the range 1753-01-01 to 9999-12-31. The datetime2 data type is capable of storing is 0001-01-01 to 9999-12-31. What data type is the column in the SQL Server table?

Comment: The data type is 'dateTime', but also [DataType(DataType.Date)]

Comment: [Display(Name = "Date of Birth"),DataType(DataType.Date),DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

Comment: That is C#. What is the column type in SQL Server?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not exactly sure how to find that, https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeKlu.png here is a link to the sql table? Not sure if this helps

Comment: The Birthdate in the SQL server table is a datetime. Change it to a datetime2.